Getting suspiscious wrong results when evaluating definite integral over spatial frequency
I'm currently facing a problem evaluating an integral from this paper (page 36 ff.)
$$
\int_{all \,\xi} |H_{post}(\xi)H_{eye}(\xi)|^2d\xi
$$
where $\xi$ is a spatial frequency and
$$
H_{post}(\xi) = e^{-0.035\xi^2}\\
H_{eye}(\xi) = e^{-2.2\xi/SMAG}
$$
SMAG is a magnification factor and said to be equal to 10.
The problem is that the paper says that the result of the integral is 3.2, but when using MATLAB or Wolfram alpha, I obtain 1.6. I'm integrating over the positive range of the function, because $\xi$ denotes a spatial frequency, which cannot be negative in my understanding. When I change the integration borders from [0,$\infty$] to [-1.25, $\infty$], the result is correct. When looking at the graph of the function, it looks like a gaussian with its maximum in the negative area and some outliers going into the positive area. When integrating from [-$\infty$, $\infty$], the result is ~13.7.  My question is: what am i doing wrong? Why is my result wrong by a factor of 2, despite the instructions being very clear?
Thanks in advance

I have the exact same values as you. It is hard to tell where a possible error occurred in the text. My only guess is they are integrating over the whole real line but made the tragic error of assuming the function was even about $0$ and simply doubled the value to get $3.2$.
